# getting content from a class in another

Tags: java, class, swt

i'm actually making a swt based programm.
By trying to cleanup my code, i came accross a problem.
I want to put the "Declaration of the groups and buttons" into a new class, but therefore i need to send the `shell` object into my new class.
How can i do that? 
(If i send the `shell` object into the constructor it will **NOT** work).
Here a SSCCE of my problem :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

public class Class1 
{
  static Shell shell;

  protected void createContents() 
  {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(800, 600));
     shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(242, 242, 242));
     shell.setSize(815, 600);
     shell.setText("Test");

     /*
     * Declaration of the groups and buttons
     */
     Group areaA = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Button btn1 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn2 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn3 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Group areaB = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Spinner spin1 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin2 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin3 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin4 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Button btnA = new Button(areaB, SWT.CHECK);

     /*
     * Processing of the buttons (short example)
     */
     areaA.setBounds(52, 46, 383, 210);
     btn1.setBounds(10, 10, 85, 16);
     btn1.setText("Button1");
     btn2.setBounds(10, 56, 85, 16);
     btn2.setText("Button2");
     btn3.setBounds(10, 111, 85, 16);
     btn3.setText("Button3");
     areaB.setBounds(52, 274, 383, 192);
     spin1.setBounds(193, 34, 47, 21);
     spin2.setBounds(282, 34, 47, 21);
     spin3.setBounds(193, 82, 47, 21);
     spin4.setBounds(282, 82, 47, 21);
     btnA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
     {
       @Override
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
       {

       }
     });
     btnA.setBounds(10, 34, 85, 16);
     btnA.setText("Select range a");
     Button btnB = new Button(areaB, SWT.CHECK);
     btnB.setBounds(10, 87, 85, 16);
     btnB.setText("Select range b");
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   /*
    * Creating and disposing of the window
    */
   Display display = Display.getDefault();
   try 
   {
    Class1 window = new Class1();
    window.createContents();
    shell.layout();
    shell.setVisible(true);
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
    {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
      {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Do you have an idea how to make this properly ?

**EDIT** :
First try to put the whole in two different classes:

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import test.Class2;

public class Class2 
{
  public Class2(Shell shell) 
  {
    /*
    * Declaration of the groups and buttons
    */
     Group areaA = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Button btn1 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn2 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn3 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Group areaB = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Spinner spin1 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin2 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin3 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin4 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Button btnA = new Button(areaB, SWT.CHECK);
    }
 }
```

And now the call and use of Class2 (modified example from the SSCCE) :

```
 protected void createContents() 
 {
  shell = new Shell();
  shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(800, 600));
  shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(242, 242, 242));
  shell.setSize(815, 600);
  shell.setText("Test");

  Class2 buttons = new Class2(shell);
  /*
  * Processing of the buttons (short example)
  */
  buttons.areaA.setBounds(52, 46, 383, 210);
  buttons.btn1.setBounds(10, 10, 85, 16);
  buttons.btn1.setText("Button1");
  buttons.btn2.setBounds(10, 56, 85, 16);
  buttons.btn2.setText("Button2");
  buttons.btn3.setBounds(10, 111, 85, 16);
  buttons.btn3.setText("Button3");
  buttons.areaB.setBounds(52, 274, 383, 192);
  buttons.spin1.setBounds(193, 34, 47, 21);
  buttons.spin2.setBounds(282, 34, 47, 21);
  buttons.spin3.setBounds(193, 82, 47, 21);
  buttons.spin4.setBounds(282, 82, 47, 21);
  buttons.btnA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
  {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
    {

     }
  });
  buttons.btnA.setBounds(10, 34, 85, 16);
  buttons.btnA.setText("Select range a");
  Button btnB = new Button(buttons.areaB, SWT.CHECK);
  btnB.setBounds(10, 87, 85, 16);
  btnB.setText("Select range b");
}
```

This example will **NOT** work

The other solution i thought of, would be to put the declarative part into the body of class2, but then the `Shell` object is missing, and i don't know how to give an object to a class without getting it through the constructor.

---

Here a SSCCE of my problem : 
I want to put the "Declaration of the groups and buttons" into a new class, but therefore i need to send the `shell` object into my new class.
How can i do that? 
(If i send the `shell` object into the constructor it will **NOT** work).

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

public class Class1 
{
  static Shell shell;

  protected void createContents() 
  {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(800, 600));
     shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(242, 242, 242));
     shell.setSize(815, 600);
     shell.setText("Test");

     /*
     * Declaration of the groups and buttons
     */
     Group areaA = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Button btn1 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn2 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Button btn3 = new Button(areaA, SWT.CHECK);
     Group areaB = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
     Spinner spin1 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin2 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin3 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Spinner spin4 = new Spinner(areaB, SWT.BORDER);
     Button btnA = new Button(areaB, SWT.CHECK);

     /*
     * Processing of the buttons (short example)
     */
     areaA.setBounds(52, 46, 383, 210);
     btn1.setBounds(10, 10, 85, 16);
     btn1.setText("Button1");
     btn2.setBounds(10, 56, 85, 16);
     btn2.setText("Button2");
     btn3.setBounds(10, 111, 85, 16);
     btn3.setText("Button3");
     areaB.setBounds(52, 274, 383, 192);
     spin1.setBounds(193, 34, 47, 21);
     spin2.setBounds(282, 34, 47, 21);
     spin3.setBounds(193, 82, 47, 21);
     spin4.setBounds(282, 82, 47, 21);
     btnA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
     {
       @Override
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
       {

       }
     });
     btnA.setBounds(10, 34, 85, 16);
     btnA.setText("Select range a");
     Button btnB = new Button(areaB, SWT.CHECK);
     btnB.setBounds(10, 87, 85, 16);
     btnB.setText("Select range b");
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   /*
    * Creating and disposing of the window
    */
   Display display = Display.getDefault();
   try 
   {
    Class1 window = new Class1();
    window.createContents();
    shell.layout();
    shell.setVisible(true);
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
    {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
      {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: "if i sent the shell object to the constructor of my new object, i can't set the background anymore." How comes? what error do you get in that case?

Comment: @EtienneMiret
As i try to access the elements of my new object (let's call it "Buttons"), he says : "grpOptions cannot be resolved or is not a field"
Here is what i did : I did put all the buttons and groups into the constructor of the class Buttons, i instanciated my new object by doing `Buttons buttons = new Buttons(shell);` and i tryed to access the object by doing : ` buttons.grpOptions.setText("Options");`
As far as i understand my misstake, i should but the buttons and groups into the body of my new class "Buttons", but there i need my Shell object, how can i get it there?

Comment: Can you create a an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that explains your problem? I'm still struggling to understand what the problem is...

Comment: Just remove the `static` `Shell` variable and pass your `Shell` to `createContents(Shell shell)`.

Comment: @Baz It's a good idea i think, but it still won't work.. (And i edited the question, and added the best way i thought of).

Comment: @trolologuy Ok, please explain to me why you want to do it this way. Maybe start with what you actually want to achieve (*what*, not *how*).

Comment: @Baz Well, i would like to find a solution to that, because my GUI is a bit of messy, and way to fat. So i thought if i put my buttons, ... into a separate object i would gain space but also it would make the modifications onto the buttons more modulable.
But maybe i'm making a wrong architecture?

Comment: So you want a class that contains `static` methods to append a couple of buttons to a `Composite` that you pass to it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below to get an idea as to how to create a utility class that adds `Widget`s to a `Composite`. Keep in mind that this is just dummy code, since I have no idea what you actually want to achieve:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    ButtonUtils.addThreeLabels(new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE));
    ButtonUtils.addFourButtons(new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class ButtonUtils
{
    public static void addFourButtons(Composite parent)
    {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, true));
        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("Button " + i);
            button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        }
    }

    public static void addThreeLabels(Composite parent)
    {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.PUSH);
            label.setText("Label " + i);
            label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HePNp.jpg) is what i would like to do.
Everything is just working fine, except that i would like to make the whole thing lighter, therefore make the whole code more dynamical and avoiding to use simillar code everywhere.
That is why i want to set the whole instanciation of the different buttons, ... in a separate object (it takes less space in the gui file, and it's more easy to work on the different buttons once they all are in the same object).
Correct me if i am wrong?
(and i used composite elements for the different elements).

Comment: @trolologuy You can easily do that with the example I provided. Feel free to ask any specific questions if you have any.

Comment: Yeah, thank you i did it with the advices you provided me over the last few days, so i did it with Composites and FormLayout to get the element easily to the places i wanted them to be (GridData was by far not as easy to use in my opinion).
So you would say i should forget my idea of passing the shell element to the new object?
Your technique is interesting, now i just need a way to figure out how to use it with what i already did...i thought my idea was way easier.

Comment: @trolologuy Well, quite frankly I don't see the point. If you just want to move the code to another class and only use it from one place, you might as well just move it to another method instead of another class.

Comment: My class is about 800 lines long, subdivised in different sub methods, but i think the whole thing is beyond dirty, i mean if you want to change things it's frankly not so easy.
Therefore making a method as you suggested IS a good idea, but quite complicated for my purpose (i need the buttons to deactivate others for e.g), that's why i thought of making a class for the creation of my buttons into the shell and another file for some easy to generalize options + basic configuration.
Do you have any other idea(s)?
Do you need me to be more precise?

Comment: @trolologuy For starters you could use the JFace `Wizard` instead of what looks like a custom wizard dialog. That should make your code more modular.